# SQL Server Aliases and Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this.

| project | Cost | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | 23 | 34 |
| 3 | 22 | 53 |

I would like to create an alias project (let's say project 23) that sums up values of Cost and Balance columns for projects 2 and 3 only.
Is there a way to do that in SQL Server?

I expect this to be the outcome.

| project | Cost | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | 23 | 34 |
| 3 | 22 | 53 |
| 23 | 45 | 87 |

Comment: *create an alias project* - what does this mean? Please provide expected output.

Comment: for alias I am thinking another project (project 23 in my example). editing my post to specify the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrongly put 55 in column 2 instead of 45 but you can achieve this result using UNION ALL syntax -

```
SELECT project, Cost, Balance
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 UNION ALL
SELECT 23 AS project, SUM(Cost), SUM(Balance)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE project IN (2, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I correct the table as you suggested. My resulting table, doesn't seem to create a row for the new project number.

Comment: @ShawnA, Please try the edited query.

Comment: Thank you. One more wrinkle. I have additional columns that I don't want to merge.  I believe, Union All expects the same number of of expressions in the second SELECT. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It's correct. If you don't want to merge other columns, Simply use NULL in the last query for those columns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if grouping sets are really the right tool for your problem. You can generate a solution using them though:

```
select
    coalesce(project, max(case when project in (2, 3) then 23 end)) as project,
    sum(cost), sum(balance)
from Projects
group by grouping sets (case when project in (2, 3) then 23 end, project)
having grouping(project) = 0 or max(case when project in (2, 3) then 23 end) is not null
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce2d7510a5cc926d03b1f0b0e51d65c1

If this is really just a one-off for only these two project numbers it's probably easier to do the simple union:

```
select project, cost, balance
from Projects
union all
select 23, sum(cost), sum(balance)
from Projects
where project in (2, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you. the script doesn't seem to create an additional row for me.

Comment: @ShawnA I can't imagine why that would be. They both return four rows using the dbfiddle link for me. There must be some additional logic in your query.